# ES6 Modules/Imports in Apache Cordova Hybrid App Throw MIME Type Error

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, hybrid-mobile-app, es6-modules

I'm trying to use ES6 Modules in a hybrid mobile app built using Apache Cordova. Unfortunately, Cordova seems to be serving the module without a MIME type, which is throwing an error in the WebView (In both Chrome 63 and 64 beta).

Specifically, the deployed app (using [chrome remote debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)) throws the following error:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I'm using a bog standard ES6 import, which is now supported in the targeted version of chrome.

```
<!--index.html-->
<script type="module">
    import App from "./app.js"
    import config from "./config.js"
    window.app = new App(config)
</script>
```

Everything works properly when the prebuild assets are served over a webserver rather than deployed through Cordova. Transpiling through Babel might be an option, but it seems like a huge headache and I'd rather not go down that path until I know there's no better option.

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe related https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wound up solving this problem by using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to compile all of my code and assets into a single file. This allowed the use of import syntax without all of the associated problems in Apache Cordova. It's not as good as native support, but it was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

File system fetched files do not have a MIME type, but due to a tightened security ES6 modules must be served only with "application/javascript" MIME type.

As a workaround you may include (like I did) a web server in your app. See, for example, [cordova-httpd](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18658234)

Comment: Actually, the answer is just in the 1st sentence. If the link is gone the 2nd sentence is irrelevant -- someone will need to find an alternative software.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by just removing all the occurrences of ***type="module"*** in the cordova project.

Comment: Only javascript code of type "module" supports the native 'import' keyword. So, removiing type="module" will also remove the support for 'import'

Answer (score -1):

Using ES6 might not necessary for the Apache Cordova app. Since the app will load the script using **file_url** where it does not understand the 'type=module'. In web application, where the scripts are loaded from the server, 'type=module' will not be an issue. 

ES6 generated script will be lesser in size compared to ES5, so it makes sense to load a lesser size file from the server. But in the Cordova app, the file is accessed internally so using the ES5 will not make much difference.