# How to import an npm_module in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, import, module

I'm using Cordova to make a cross-platform app. My method so far has been to first make something work on my PC (since debugging is easy in google chrome) and then test it on my phone.

I need to import the module 'axios' that I installed with npm. The index.html includes the javascript file: *js/index.js*. Inside this file I tried loading the module by writing:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

However, this gives me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". I then tried importing the module from *index.html*:

```
<script type="module" src="../node_modules/axios/index.js"></script>
```

But it then throws a security error:

```
Access to script at '<path-to-app-root>/node_modules/axios/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

When I google the error I find workarounds (that I also cannot get to work). But I feel it shouldn't be this hard since I'm working with a well-known framework. For example, I tried the method used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113359/es6-modules-imports-in-apache-cordova-hybrid-app-throw-mime-type-error) but once again I get a security error.

I'm at a loss here. Should I use a complex workaround from the internet or am I missing the regular/easy way?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Node with Cordova. Node.JS is a back end environment.

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate a bit? Does this mean I cannot use axios?

Comment: I don't know Axios but it seems like they have a front end lib <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

Comment: There is a plugin you should look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mobile-cordova